# db.commit to change password (db not updating)

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

I would like to change a users password in db using db.session.commit()

I am getting the appropriate flash for form validation. But on next login, the db change does not go through / I cannot login with the newly created password. The old password is the one that needs to be used on the next login.

```
from Portfolio import db, login_manager
from Portfolio import bcrypt
from flask_login import UserMixin


@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(user_id):
    return User.query.get(int(user_id))


class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(length=30), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(length=60), nullable=False)

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self.password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, plain_text_password):
        self.password_hash = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(plain_text_password)

    def check_password_correction(self, attempted_password):
        return bcrypt.check_password_hash(self.password_hash, attempted_password)
```

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///database.db'
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'c133ce687016b5000d7b56cc81e0d974c9f1b0730836b4997765c34c7f417c56'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
bcrypt = Bcrypt(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view = "login_page"
login_manager.login_message_category = "info"

from Portfolio import routes
```

```
class ResetForm(FlaskForm):
    def validate_reset(self, reset_to_check):
        password = User.query.filter_by(password_hash=reset_to_check.data).first()
        if password:
            raise ValidationError('Please input a proper password')
    resetpass = PasswordField(label='Reset Password',
                              validators=[Regexp('^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{12,}$'),
                                          Length(min=12), DataRequired()])
    confreset = PasswordField(label='Confirm Changed Password:', validators=[EqualTo('resetpass'), DataRequired()])
    newsubmit = SubmitField(label='Submit New Password')
```

```
@app.route('/reset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def reset():
    form = ResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.username
        reset_password = User(password=form.resetpass.data)
        user.password = reset_password
        db.session.commit()
        logout_user()
        flash('Password has been changed. Please login.')
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    return render_template('reset.html', form=form, date=format_date, time=format_time)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that validation step passed?

Here you compared the incoming data (probably not hashed) with hashed password in db.

```py
        password = User.query.filter_by(password_hash=reset_to_check.data).first()
        if password:
            raise ValidationError('Please input a proper password')
```

I assume that it will always be `None`, so no raise.

Second thing, you assign new `User` instance (why creating a new user?) to `reset_password` variable and afterwards assign this `User` instance under `reset_password` to `user.reset_password` atrribute. It is awkward and wrong for me. You should reset password for `current_user` :

```
from flask_login import current_user, logout_user

@app.route('/reset', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def reset():
    form = ResetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = current_user
        user.password = resetpass.data
        db.session.commit()
        logout_user()
        flash('Password has been changed. Please login.')
        return redirect(url_for('login_page'))
    return render_template('reset.html', form=form, date=format_date, time=format_time)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping out. I was able to make the following changes which allowed the db.session.commit() to go through. Thank you very much!